# Make UI changes in MainActivity from helper class

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, listener

I am trying to put in app billing in my android app. I am currently stuck on how to call back to my MainActivity to perform a UI change from the helper billing class once it is found the user has previously bought something.

I have searched and searched but I cannot find what I'm looking for, I'm sure I need to implement a callback or a listener or both?

My code is the following:

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  {


MyBilling bill;
private Menu nav_Menu;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

bill = new MyBilling(this);
bill.onCreate();

}

private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId) {

///calls fragment and inflates

}


public void UpdateUI(){

//Make some changes to UI
nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.remove_ad_button).setVisible(false);

//Recall fragment
displaySelectedScreen(R.id.distance_check);

}


}
```

Billing helper class (Google In App Billing)

```
public class MyBilling {

Activity activity;
public MyBilling(Activity launcher) {
    this.activity = launcher;
}


IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
  public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                       Inventory inventory) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");

      // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
      if (mHelper == null)
          return;

      // Is it a failure?
      if (result.isFailure()) {
          // complain("Failed to query inventory: " + result);
          return;
      }

      Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");

      /*
       * Check for items we own. Notice that for each purchase, we check
       * the developer payload to see if it's correct! See
       * verifyDeveloperPayload().
       */

      // Do we have the premium upgrade?
      Purchase removeAdsPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_REMOVE_ADS);
      AdCheck = (removeAdsPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(removeAdsPurchase));


        //Yes there has been purchases! 
      if(AdCheck == true){
          removeAds(); // sets global flag

          //// Want to call UI change here....
          MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
          main.UpdateUI();

      }

  }
 };

 }
```

What I understand from debugging is IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener is called during oncreate of billing class, it is asynchronous, so my main activity continues to compile. When setup and reading of purchases are complete I need to go back to my MainActivity and make changes.

If anyone can point me in the right direction here please - I've tried to keep the code straight forward by just provided the needed snippets.

Comment: That's bad habit to pass activities around + you have here a circular dependency. You should use interfaces to communicate between them. http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `Interface`. Add the `UpdateUI()` method declaration in the `Interface`. Then create instance of the `Interface` in the `MyBilling` class and initialise using constructor. Call the `UPdateUI()` method throught the the instance of the `Interface`. Then implement the `Interface` in your `MainActivity`. If you are unclear about implementing, I'd be happy to post the code.

The code :

In your `MyBilling` class, add the following inside the class

```
public interface Update {
        void UpdateUI();
    }
```

Use this to call the `UpdateUI()` method from the `MyBilling` class.

```
myActivity.UpdateUI();
```

Use this as the constructor in `MyBilling` class

```
Update myActivity;
public MyBilling (Update activity) {
    myActivity = activity;
}
```

Now change to the following in the `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, MyBilling.Update
```

If a red line appear beneath it, Alt+enter it to implement the `Update` interface in `MainActivity`. I'm guessing since you already has `UpdateUI()` in your `MainActivity`, there wont be a red line error. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Joshua, Yes If you could post the code that would be amazing! I have not created an interface before!

Comment: Answer worked perfectly. Thank you. Would you mind explaining how this interface is allowing me to call methods within MainActivity without any issues?

Comment: By creating interface inside MyBilling class, your are specifying the methods that is going to be called from MyBilling class. When you are implementing the interface in the MainActivity, you are defining the methods it specifies. Thereby defining the methods thats going to be called by the class that has the interface. Hope you get an idea about it. Feel free to ask if not clear